# C# Transfer file over internet

Tags: c#, raspberry-pi, file-transfer

I have a raspberry pi operating 24/7 in a different location and I have a C# script running on my laptop. I want to transfer a file from my computer to the raspberry pi over the internet using this script. The raspberry pi and my laptop are NOT on the same local network, but both have access to internet. What is the best way to transfer the file? Can someone point me in the right direction?

The file is a text file which would be a few kilobytes long.

Comment: This is too broad of a question but also off topic as you are asking for a resource recommendation. I recommend you start by googling/searching for tutorials and if you get stuck come back and ask a specific question with details on what exactly is not working. Good luck.

Comment: Email is always a good asynchronous message transfer system.  It is used for things not related to user-driven requests all the time.  See SOAP over SMTP, MSMQ over SMTP, Active Directory SMTP sync, etc...

Comment: The simplest solution is using email to transfer your file or cloud sharing tools like Dropbox .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run a FTP server on the RPI, and port foward the router's respective ports to the RPI.

Alternatively SSH and port foward the router's respective ports to the RPI, then use SFTP.

**disclaimer, you are exposing your PI to the internet**

Comment: I have googled a lot and this is the methodology I will be following. I will first set up an FTP server on the raspberry pi. I will configure my router to forward all packets received on port 21 (FTP) to the IP address of Raspberry Pi. After that, I will find my routers public IP address (which can be found by googling it). I will FTP into this IP address and transfer the file. Is this the right approach I am using?

Comment: Yes.  You may run into issues with Active vs Passive which may require opening some more ports and configuring a range for the FTP server - but Google will be your friend there.